# Linking GoogleTest and CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, googletest

I'm afraid that it is a basic problem, I might have found the answer with other IDEs but not with CodeBlocks =(

I try to use GoogleTest. I downloaded the project, built it with cmake -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" (I'm on Ubuntu)

That gave me the libgtest.a and libgtest_main.a files that I transfered in /usr/lib

And I think my lacks are on the last step : linking GoogleTest and CodeBlocks. Some tutorials told to add the "-lgtest" linker option, I tried many things but it's all the same : when I try to compile my #include "gtest/gtest.h" returns the fatal error "No such file or directory".

Could you help my poor soul ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put files that you have built yourself under `/usr/...`
unless you put them under `/usr/local/...`. The rest of `/usr/...`
is reserved by your Linux distro and should be exclusively populated by your package manager. If you mess about in it behind the package manager's back,
you risk breaking your packages and getting into any amount of pain.

First remove `libgtest.a` and `libgtest_main.a` from `/usr/lib`.

You've downloaded `googletest` and built it in some directory by first
running `CMake` in that directory and then running `make`.

Having done that, in the same directory where you ran `make`, run:

```
sudo make install
```

This will install all the `gmock` / `gtest` libraries in `/usr/local/lib`.
It will install the `gmock` header files in `/usr/local/include/gmock` and install
the `gtest` header files in `/usr/local/include/gtest`. Go there and check.

`/usr/local/...` belongs to *you* and whatever you do there will not interfere
with the package manager.

Next, to use `googletest` in your unit-testing program, you might need to do the following
6 things:

**1:** `#include <gtest/gtest.h>` where applicable in your source files. (Note:
    `<gtest/gtest.h>`, and not anything different).

**2:** Tell the compiler what directory contains `gtest/gtest.h`, unless
    it's one of the compiler's default search directories. To do that, you would
    pass the option `-I/usr/local/include` to `g++` for compiling the source files. But you don't need to
    do that, because `/usr/local/include` *is* one of the compiler's default search
    directories.

**3:** Tell the linker that you want to link `libgtest.a`. To do that that, you
    pass the option `-lgtest` to `g++` for linking the program.

**4:** Tell the linker what directory contains `libgest.a`, unless
    it's one of the linker's default search directories. To do that, you would
    pass the option `-L/usr/local/lib` to `g++` for linking the program. But you don't need to
    do that, because `/usr/local/lib` *is* one of the linker's default search
    directories.

**5:** Tell the compiler to generate thread-safe code. (Why? Because by default,
    `libgest` is a multi-threaded library. You can build it single-threaded if you
    want, but I assume you didn't.) To do that, you pass the option `-pthread`
    to `g++` for compiling source files.

**6:** Tell the linker to link a multi-threading executable. To do that, you pass the option
    `-pthread` to `g++` for linking the program. (Yes, `-pthread` for compiling and
    `-pthread` again for linking).

So in practice you just need to do **1**, **3**, **5** and **6**.

**1** needs no futher explanation. The rest require you to set up your Code::Blocks project
**Build options** correctly, so that they generate the correct `g++ ...` commands for compiling and
linking.

It looks as if you've already got **3** right: In **Build options...** -> **Linker settings** ->
**Other linker options**, add the line: `-lgtest`

For **5**, in **Build options...** -> **Compiler settings** -> **Other compiler options**, add the line: `-pthread`

For **6**, in **Build options...** -> **Linker settings** -> **Other linker options**, add another line: `-pthread`,
after the one with `-lgtest`.

That's all. When you've saved those settings you can build your project. If there are errors, youi can look at the
build log under the **Build log** tab (not the **Build messages** tab) to see exactly what `g++ ...` commands
got executed for compiling and linking, and if your settings produced the correct commandline options for `g++`.

Comment: You're a angel, that works perfectly now. May your days be long and your nights be pleasant.