# Finding libgtest linker library for codeblocks ide

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, googletest

I am trying to run gtest on the codeblocks ide in ubuntu 17.10. It keeps coming back with `undefined reference to "x"` error.

After some googling it seems that that the ide is missing linker libraries for gtest. Where may I find the linker libraries for gtest?

I have installed gtest using this command:

`sudo apt install libgtest-dev`

and test built it using this command:

`g++ -I /usr/include/gtest -I /usr/src/gtest/ -c /usr/src/gtest/src/gtest-all.cc`

Comment: Run `locate libgtest` is you do not know or don't remember where you installed it.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you, but that command does not find `libgtest.a` or `libgtest.so`.

Comment: In that case you haven't installed them. Would have expected you to
have compilation errors before linkage errors in that case, but there's
no telling as you've posted no code.

Comment: have install libgtest-dev and built it. There is no need for code as stated its a linker issue.

Comment: Please add to your post the steps by which you built `libgtest-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer by `Some programmer` referencing [linking googletestand codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324589/linking-googletest-and-codeblocks)

I found libgtest.a and pthread in the following directories:

`/usr/lib/libgtest.a`

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so`

I added the two files through Settings --> Compiler... --> Linker Settings

My test now compiles.

Answer (score 1):

The linker to gtest is `-lgtest` wich you should add in project/build options/Linker settings -> other linker options. Make sure to select the right target (Debug/release) on the left menu.

A good step by step guide has been made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324589/linking-googletest-and-codeblocks)